# H1 gives me a white background color on the text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a header on top of this image with a gradient that I've made but it gives me a weird white background as such https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppuJq.png I want the text on top of the image to have a transparent background. Made the navbar black so its easier to see but anyway, how do I remove it? I am aware that the js script is unfinished if that has anything to do with it.

here is my code

```css
/*
CSS for the page:
*/

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.WelcomeMenu h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.WelcomeMenu img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
}

.img-gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
}

.img-gradient::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85));
}

.MiddleMenu {
  color: #FFFF;
  height: 600vh;
}


/*
CSS for navbar: 
*/

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

nav {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #000;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

nav .fa {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

.nav-list .active {
  color: #F10000;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-list img {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: -35px;
}

.nav-list {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F10000;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-list ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.nav-list ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .nav-list ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-list {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    height: 125vh;
    width: 175px;
    top: 0;
    right: -300px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  .nav-list ul li a {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .nav-list ul li {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<title> Lookout </title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/%22%3E">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-list" id="navList">
      <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="/index.html" class="active"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/sub/check/check.html"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="https://www.medietilsynet.no/"> AAAAAA </a> </li>

        <a href="https://www.medietilsynet.no/"> <img src="Bilder/Medietilsynet.png"></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
  </nav>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="WelcomeMenu">
    <h1> STOP THINK & CHECK. </H1>


    <div class="img-gradient">
      <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/quackquackquest/_/rsrc/1469302829712/duck-duck-maps/duck%20banner%203.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="MiddleMenu">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Note that we don't have access to your folder structure, so "Bilder/BG1.jpg" is resulting in a broken image. Replace that with a reference to publicly available image if the image is important to the question.

Comment: @tacoshy I don't see Bootstrap being used in the code. The Font Awesome CSS is being pulled from bootstrapcdn.com, but not Bootstrap itself. If I edited it out by mistake, please do add it back in.

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh right my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the background color on body tag and the *transparent* background on `.WelcomeMenu`. Ways to fix (Only one of them):

1. Add a background color to `.WelcomeMenu`
2. Have a parent element and set the background color to black
3. Make the background color of body black

```css
/*
CSS for the page:
*/
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.WelcomeMenu {
  background-color: red
}

.WelcomeMenu h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.WelcomeMenu img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
}

.img-gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
}

.img-gradient::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85));
}

.MiddleMenu {
  color: #FFFF;
  height: 600vh;
}


/*
CSS for navbar: 
*/

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

nav {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #000;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

nav .fa {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

.nav-list .active {
  color: #F10000;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-list img {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: -35px;
}

.nav-list {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F10000;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-list ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.nav-list ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .nav-list ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-list {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    height: 125vh;
    width: 175px;
    top: 0;
    right: -300px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  .nav-list ul li a {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .nav-list ul li {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<title> Lookout </title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/%22%3E">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-list" id="navList">
      <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="/index.html" class="active"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/sub/check/check.html"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="https://www.medietilsynet.no/"> AAAAAA </a> </li>

        <a href="https://www.medietilsynet.no/"> <img src="Bilder/Medietilsynet.png"></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
  </nav>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="WelcomeMenu">
    <h1> STOP THINK & CHECK. </H1>


    <div class="img-gradient">
      <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/quackquackquest/_/rsrc/1469302829712/duck-duck-maps/duck%20banner%203.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="MiddleMenu">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! However I'm trying to get the background of H1 to be transparent not black (my fault for not clearing that up), how do I make it transparent instead?.

Comment: Elements background is transparent by default. You can avoid adding `background-color: transparent` to h1.

Comment: Thats weird because I have no body color set in the css, yet it still gives me a background color of the h1 tag, even though the only thing I named for h1 was font-size.

Answer (score 0):

The image that you are using is a *background* image! so for a better solution you can make it the background of the `div.WelcomeMenu`.

The white color is the background of the page (by default - which is blank white page). and the order of the elements is:

```
Navbar - black background
h1 - the background of the page 
img - the image itself
```

that means, the `h1` is between the two elements.

In case you still want the elements as they are, you can simply add:

```
.WelcomeMenu {
   position: relative;
}

.WelcomeMenu h1 {
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px; (change it as you wish)
   left: 100px; (change it as you wish)
}
```

**The Code:**

```css
/*
CSS for the page:
*/

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.WelcomeMenu {
  position: relative;
  height: 85vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)),
                  url("https://sites.google.com/site/quackquackquest/_/rsrc/1469302829712/duck-duck-maps/duck%20banner%203.jpg");
  background-repeat:  no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.WelcomeMenu h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.MiddleMenu {
  color: #FFFF;
  height: 600vh;
}

/*
CSS for navbar: 
*/

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

nav {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #000;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

nav .fa {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

.nav-list .active {
  color: #F10000;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-list img {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: -35px;
}

.nav-list {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F10000;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-list ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.nav-list ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .nav-list ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-list {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    height: 125vh;
    width: 175px;
    top: 0;
    right: -300px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  .nav-list ul li a {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .nav-list ul li {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<title> Lookout </title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/%22%3E">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-list" id="navList">
      <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="/index.html" class="active"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/sub/check/check.html"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/"> AAAA </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="https://www.medietilsynet.no/"> AAAAAA </a> </li>

        <a href="https://www.medietilsynet.no/"> <img src="Bilder/Medietilsynet.png"></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
  </nav>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="WelcomeMenu">
    <h1> STOP THINK & CHECK. </h1>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this really did help!

Comment: I'm glad that helped... Voting will be appreciated :)